# predicting a single image in keras (dimension problem)

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, deep-learning, prediction

I think I 've got a common dimension problem with Keras. I try to use a pre-trained model ('model.h5') in order to
predict the class of a single test image ('test.jpg').

With the following code:

```
model = load_model('model.h5')
model.summary()
# load dataset


# evaluate the model
score = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], score[1]*100))
```

I'm getting this information about the model:

[image]

Now, after running,

```
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

model.predict(img)
```

I get the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-43-c2dfe8703a1b> in <module>()
      1 img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
      2 
----> 3 model.predict(img)

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1439 
   1440         # Case 2: Symbolic tensors or Numpy array-like.
-> 1441         x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
   1442         if self.stateful:
   1443             if x[0].shape[0] > batch_size and x[0].shape[0] % batch_size != 0:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    577             feed_input_shapes,
    578             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 579             exception_prefix='input')
    580 
    581         if y is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    133                         ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
    134                         str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 135                         'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
    136                 if not check_batch_axis:
    137                     data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (194, 259, 3)
```

I was trying some codes from similar questions, but nothing works for me. What am I missing here? Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: its looks like your model.predict function expecting a 4 dimensions, 3 of them could be the image channels and 4rth dimension could be number of images on which the model needs to predict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error comes when the image dimensions which you are using do not match with the one used for training the model.
The shape for your image is (194, 259, 3),
but the model expects something like this : (1, 194, 259, 3), because you are using a single sample. You can take help of `numpy.expand_dims()` to get the required dimensions.

```py
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
model.predict(img)
```

Comment: `np.expand_dims()` should come after reading image.  Edit: I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. As a result I've got a very long list of arrays. Is this the 'predction'?

Comment: @Thesinus use model.predict_classes(img) for a class/category output. Alternatively, you can use `np.argmax`